# Js code skips first line after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per my following code "Processing" is not appending first instead it directly append "Saving". I tried solve this but not getting whats wrong in my code that it is not working and skipping first "Processing" line.

```
    $('#ac_submit,#save_as_draft').click(function (e) {

        $('#save_as_draft').append('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Processing');
        $('form').find('.invalid_field').removeClass('invalid_field');
        var  validation_status = 0;
        $('#mandate_field').empty();
        $('input,textarea,select').filter('[required]').each(function(){
            if($(this).filter('[required]').val() == ''){
//                console.log($(this).filter('[required]').attr('name'));
               $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass(' has-error has-danger');
               $('#ac_submit').removeClass('disabled');
               $('#save_as_draft').removeClass('disabled');
               if($(this).closest('.hide_devices').hasClass('show_panel') == true){
                   $('#panel').addClass('invalid_field');
                   var matched_li = $(this).closest('div[id^="tab_"]').attr('id');
                   $('li a[href="#'+matched_li+'"]').addClass('invalid_field');
               } else {    
                   var divId = $(this).closest('.hide_devices').attr('id');
                   $('li a[div-id="'+divId+'"]').addClass('invalid_field')
                   var action_on_li = divId.replace(/\d+/g, '')
                   if(action_on_li == 'cloneModBusInput'){
                       $('#mod__bus').addClass('invalid_field')
                   }
                   if(action_on_li == 'cloneSensorInput'){
                       $('#sen__sor').addClass('invalid_field')
                   }
                   if(action_on_li == 'clonedRelayInput'){
                       $('#re__lay').addClass('invalid_field')
                   }
               }
               $('#mandate_field').empty().html('* Mandatory fields are missing');
               validation_status = 1;
                $(this).addClass('disabled');
                $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-save"></i> '+$(this).text()+'');
               e.preventDefault();
            } 
        });
        if(validation_status == 0){
            $('#mandate_field').empty();
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Saving');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-save"></i> '+$(this).text()+'');
        }
    });
```

please help me identify whats wrong in the above code.

Comment: Can we see the html as well?

Comment: would be a lot easier with HTML or even a demo on JSfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs synchronously. What you do is append an element to a container, and several lines down replace the entire html content of the same element with new content. The result is what you describe to be getting.

If you want to see the previous content for half a second do the following:

```
var self = this;

setTimeout(function () {
    if (validation_status == 0) {
        $('#mandate_field').empty();
        $(self).addClass('disabled');
        $(self).html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Saving');
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Works Perfactly

Answer (score 0):

That's because you override your "Processing":

```
$('#save_as_draft').append('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Processing');
```

Here:

```
 $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Saving');
```

Comment: No actually it is save button, but when i click on save button then it should first show processing and execute further code then it goes to "saving" but it waits for few second  as a save button and directly show "saving" and then form submitted